Access directory of hostmachine during docker build - Gitlab Runner
I am currently working on the CICD pipeline for our web project. It is a C# blazor web application.
Since we are using our own Nuget packages, I need to install/add our local certificate authority during the build stage. Otherwise, the Nuget packages cannot be retrieved.
Currently, the certificate is part of the project. However, I would prefer to store this certificate in a directory on the host machine and access it during the pipeline. (If you have other recommendations, I'd be happy to take them too.)
This way, each of our projects can access it.
I start the Gitlab runner as a Docker container with the following volume: -v /usr/local/share/ca-certificates:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
Logically, the corresponding CA certificates are located under /usr/local/share/ca-certificates on the host machine.
In the runner config, I have specified the volume accordingly in the [runners.docker] section: volumes = [..., "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates"]
Finally, I added the volume to the Dockerfile accordingly: VOLUME /usr/local/share/ca-certificates:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
However, the subsequent update-ca-certificates command does not find any files.
Is this the correct procedure? In my understanding, the structure would be as shown in this diagram:

I would be very grateful for any help!
Best regards
Lukas

the subsequent update-ca-certificates command does not find any files Can ls find them? Can cat print them? Where is the "update-ca-certificates" executed? Is this the correct procedure? at my work, I release basic docker images with injected private certificates in them and publish on our local nexus docker repo.

The Dockerfile VOLUME directive can't specify what outside Docker will be bound to a specific container directory.  If the CA certificate will be in a well-known place, and your CI step can copy it into the build context, can you COPY it into the image?

The best way is probably to make a custom build image that already contains the certificate and push that to an internal docker repository. Then use that for your build processes.

As proposed by @Hans Kilian, I made my custom images with the ca-certificates already installed and use them for the build processes.
That works like a charm.
Thanks!
